# Function inside a ReactJS called many times

Tags: reactjs

I am using Ionic React and load local data using a plugin.I call that function only once but it gets called many times

Main.jsx

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react';
import {
    IonApp, 
    IonHeader,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonContent,
    IonInput,
    IonList,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
    IonButton
} from '@ionic/react';
import 'capacitor-secure-storage-plugin';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { SecureStoragePlugin } = Plugins;


    const MainPage=  () => {
        const [username,setUsername]=useState("h");
        const [token,setToken]=useState("blah");
        const bogusFunctionForAsyncOperations = async () => 
        {   console.log("Hello world");
            let temp;
            let key='username';
            temp=await SecureStoragePlugin.get({ key })
              .then(value => {
                 console.log(value.value," Got username from storage  at MainPage");
                return value;
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log('Item with specified key does not exist.');
                return ( "Error at MainPage .The key is "+key);
              });
              setUsername(temp.value);
        }
        bogusFunctionForAsyncOperations();
        return (
            <>
                <p>Hello {username}! </p>
            </>
            );
        };
    export default MainPage;
```

Log

```
    main.jsx:23 Hello world
    main.jsx:28 testuser  Got username from storage  at MainPage
    main.jsx:23 Hello world
    main.jsx:28 testuser  Got username from storage  at MainPage
    main.jsx:23 Hello world
    main.jsx:28 testuser  Got username from storage  at MainPage
```

1.How do I fix this?
2.Is there a better way to do `await` instead of putting all `await` inside an 'async'?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `React.useEffect`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   bogusFunctionForAsyncOperations();
}, []);
```

The problem being since your function run in your first render, it updates the state again which triggers another re-render and there it starts an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put the function call `bogusFunctionForAsyncOperations()` inside `useEffect()`

at the moment it gets executed every time you set the state